# Prove equalities using exponential generating functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, analysis, power-series

I want to show $e^{ax}+e^{bx} = e^{(a+b)x} $. I have that $ \sum_{n>0} \frac {(ax)^n}{n!} \sum_{n>0} \frac {(bx)^n}{n!} $ is the first step but I'm unsure of the specifics of how to then go from the multiplication of the two exponential power series, $ \sum_{n>0} (\sum_{n>0} \binom {n}{i} a_i b_{n-i})\frac{x^n}{n!} $ to the final solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Taylor series
$$
e^{ax}=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^nx^n}{n!} \quad\text{and}\quad e^{bx}=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{b^nx^n}{n!}
$$
 So
$$
e^{ax}e^{ax}=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{a^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\frac{b^k}{k!}x^n=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{a^{n-k}b^k}{n!}x^n=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(a+b)^{n}}{n!}x^n=e^{(a+b)x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The binomial theorem states that $\sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{n}{i} a^i b^{n-i} = (a + b)^n$.